# Silverlight stopped displaying text after certain number of characters

Tags: silverlight, textbox

So I dont really touch or have touched silverlight programming but my company has this application built in it and I have a bug they want me to fix. The issue is my text box can hold up to about 778 characters or 16 rows but then you cant view anymore of what you wrote. If you copy all you get everything you wrote even though you might only see 3/4 of it. I am not sure what I need to do, if I need to create a control panel thing for over flow or set a max length, etc. What would be my best step for this? Any good ideas?

Code:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="txtDesc"  Width="300" Height="80" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ExcursionDescription, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StripNonAsciilCharacters1}}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
```

Comment: Your vertical ScrollBar doesn't allow you to scroll through the length of the content?

Comment: Should I not have one at all?

Comment: I took it off and it doesnt look great but it will let you see all the way down. Do i set it to visible or just not have one at all?

Comment: Well, with a Height of only 80 set, that's not exactly a lot of view space but I guess it would depend on the layout of your design and the requirements of the user. Do they want to see the entire content of that textbox at all times regardless of the size? Or does the design constrain your size? etc. I'm not sure what you're asking for exactly, maybe a screen shot of what it is, and what you want? :/

Comment: Yeah the design doesnt allow to view all the data but without visible scroll bars not sure the end user will know how to scroll through it. Trying to get them to see all of the data they enter in there at certain scrolls not all at once.

Comment: Your VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" tells it that if the content exceeds the available height, provide a ScrollBar, if it doesnt, then a ScrollBar is not shown. So it should be allowing you to scroll to the bottom of the content right? Can you maybe screenshot the behavior you're experiencing? Is it cutting off on the bottom, or on the sides? It's still difficult to visualize from your description.

Comment: Where is this textbox control included? Set its parent controller height to a fixed value and set this textbox height to Auto to force the ScrollBar appear.